# ¿Puedo configurar NGiNX como proxy de otro servidor en la red local?

Tags: nginx, servidor

Tengo dos servidores, uno con una ip pública y otro con una ip local dentro de la misma red. El servidor con ip pública tiene NGiNX configurado como reverse proxy de algunas apps. El servidor con ip local tiene una aplicación corriendo en el puerto 5000, algo como: `192.168.1.244:5000`, mi pregunta es si puedo usar el server con NGINX para darle salida a la aplicación ya mencionada.

Actualmente tengo una configuración asi:

```
server {

 listen 80;
 server_name mi.dominio.com;

 location / {
  proxy_pass http://192.168.1.244:5000/$uri$is_args$args;
  proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
 }

}
```

Y no funciona.

Cabe recalcar que también intenté hacer algo mas simple como redirigirlo al puerto `80`

```
server {

 listen 80;
 server_name mi.dominio.com;

 location / {
  proxy_pass http://192.168.1.244;
  proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
 }

}
```

Y eso si funcionó.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes configurar asi el nginx.

```html
server {
          listen 80;
          server_name mi.dominio.com;
          
  
          location / {
              proxy_redirect          off;
              proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
              proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
              proxy_connect_timeout   180;
              proxy_send_timeout      180;
              proxy_read_timeout      180;
              proxy_buffers           32 4k
              proxy_pass http://192.168.1.244:5000;

          }
      }
```

Comment: no funcionó, he checado el error.log de NGiNX y arroja esto:
2017/10/20 12:21:52 [crit] 5957#0: *1 connect() to 192.168.1.244:5000 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.254,

Comment: agrega **setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1** entre **proxy_buffer** y *proxy_pass**